# How to get the bounding box of a text using html5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I would like to get some text's bounding box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer before I submited the question:

http://mudcu.be/journal/2011/01/html5-typographic-metrics/#bboxUnicode
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

```
var text_width = ctx.measureText("some text").width;
```

I used line height for `text_height`.

This gives not exact bounding box, but it is fast and usable before text rendering.

Answer (score 6):

Works in Chrome:

```js
const can = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = can.getContext('2d');

let x = 10, y = 50;
let msg = "Hello, World!";

ctx.font = "30px monospace";

let textMetrics = ctx.measureText(msg);

ctx.fillText(msg, x, y);

console.log(textMetrics);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(
 x - textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft,
  y - textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent
);
ctx.lineTo(
  x + textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxRight, 
  y - textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent
);
ctx.lineTo(
  x + textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxRight, 
  y + textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent
);
ctx.lineTo(
 x - textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft,
  y + textMetrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent
);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I find polyfill for textMetrics but i dont test it: https://github.com/motiz88/canvas-text-metrics-polyfill

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but what about:

/* See w3schools box-sizing page */

```
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: OP wanted to get the size of a text.