# Is there a way to measure the bounding box of text based on font used?

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I'm having trouble with re-generating the texts as displayed in an image editor I'm creating.

So in the image editor, the user's text is displayed like https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUUzi.jpg . The width and height of the box is as you see in grey, but certain fonts will have the upper and lower lines on some letters to overflow, when I use konvajs to re-create this text as image, the top and bottom of some letters get cut off.

Is there a way to calculate the true height of the text so I can create a box that the next can fit nicely inside the box without the overflow?

I hope this make sense?

In jquery, you can get the box's scrollheight, but this is not accurate either.

Comment: Would this help? https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Comment: based on the tags and the title, is this a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836350/how-to-get-the-bounding-box-of-a-text-using-html5-canvas)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The linked dup doesn't seem to answer the question. It looks like OP wants to know the height of the text _before_  adding it to a canvas, or did I misunderstood the question ..?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question @RobG. Was looking for a method prior to using canvas so I can correctly create the size of the canvas to hold the text, I need it before the canvas step because there's positioning involved too...measuring it in during canvas will offset the positioning.

Comment: @Teemu - that doesn't work...

Comment: measureText works without rendering the text on the canvas. That's the way to go: you first measure your text then calculate the correct positions to use in fillText.

Comment: @Kaiido - Thanks but measuretext doesn't give you the height of the text, so you can't get the bounding box

Comment: @tuan.ng nothing will get it to you because z̵̛̰̠̝̥̘̻͖̳̖̫̀̽̾͒̉̓̀̆̊̄̾͆a̵͈̜̳̫͉̘̽̓̄̄̏̈̇͋̄͋̓̐́ļ̸̻̘̪̭̣̺͆̽́̀͂͜͝g̴̨̞͈̮̣̔̀͐̈͂ͅǫ̴̛̤̰̤̣̖̻͖͙̱͈̹͈͗̐̊̋̆̕̕ͅ ̴̣͓̮͓̊̿̋͆̌ͅi̷̧̟̺̞̥̎̏͋͐͑͗̾̈́̓̀͘͠͝ṣ̸̺̭͉͓̻͖̙͋̾̇̓̏̀͐̐͝ ̵̢̗̟͍̹͕̥̯̭̝̗̆̂̚ḕ̵̢̧̺̠̻̙̪͕̯̻͚̝̬͈͊̾͠ͅv̵̫̰͕̊̓̈́͂ͅȇ̶̬̙̦̭̜͍͖͒̃̅͗͛͑͝r̴̯̪̻̼̪̗̗͎̳̖͋̈̃͌̾́͗͠ͅẙ̷̧̛̞͈͓̯̅̒̇̽̕w̸̨̨̙̍͐̑̆̎̀̒͝ͅḩ̶̼͚̘̠̗͇̜̜̱͔̪̹̥͗̿͛̒͛̚̚͝ͅe̵̢̧̟̲̙̯͖̲̼͙̹̹͙̜̺̔͐̿r̴̨̯̤͎̘͇͓̫͈̪͕̀͋ë̵̠̳͕̙̰́̈́̅͛̑̽̇̃