# Get edge coordinates of text placed on html canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, text, font-size

What are some efficient methods of finding the x,y coordinates of the right and bottom edges of a paragraph of text placed on a canvas element? So far attempts to multiply number of characters times font size have proved unreliable and more difficult than expected.

For example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World, this is a sentence", 10, 50);
```

I'd like to find the exact location of the bottom right corner of the sentence placed on canvas without having to calculate it dynamically based on the font size.

Comment: what is the main goal? are you trying to find the area of the paragraph? are you trying to figure out how big you should make these paragraphs?

Comment: Show some code where you draw the text.

Comment: var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);

Could you be looking for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Comment: @devin My main goal is to draw a rectangle background for the given text that is perfectly centered with a specific margin around the edges

Comment: @schquestioner there is no calculation needed for this make another tag that encapsulates the <p> tag then use css on that tag, or just change the background color of the css on the p tag

Comment: perhaps I am not understanding the question or goal, I think you need to produce a "minimal example" so that I can put your code into my system and test to see how to fix your problem

Comment: @devin I'm using something like context.fillText("hello world", x,y) to place text on canvas, not html elements than can be encapsulated with <p> tags.

Comment: @schquestioner show me with your code what you are doing, in the question

Comment: you have to make sure the width and height of the canvas tag is equal to the size of the page then you can just do what I posted to get the bottom right cordinates

Comment: Use the code In  this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60141000/3702797 (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67015797/3702797) in a more functionnal version)